# Is it at all possible to update markers in a Google Map using SignalR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, signalr

Like the title says, is it possible to use SignalR / jquery to update for instance the color of the map markers?

I'm working on a website where a map displays different units with real time status changes, and the markers colors should reflect this as part of the functionality.

Can it be done in some way, or is the only way to set the color at "runtime"?
Currently, the map displays all of my markers just fine, in a blue color.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/GoogleAPI/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/GoogleAPI/oms.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var markerArray = [];    
    var usualColor = '0000FF';
    var spiderfiedColor = 'ffee22';
    var iconWithColor = function(color) {
        return 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_xpin_letter&chld=pin|+|' +
            color + '|000000|ffff00';
    };
    var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
        new google.maps.Size(37, 34), // size   - for sprite clipping
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin - ditto
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34) // anchor - where to meet map location
    );

    function initialize() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            },
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
        var mcOptions = {
            maxZoom: 12
        };
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

        //Overlapping marker spiderfier
        oms.addListener('click', function(marker) {
            iw.setContent(marker.desc);
            iw.open(map, marker);
        });
        oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(spiderfiedColor));
                markers[i].setShadow(null);
            }
            iw.close();
        });
        oms.addListener('unspiderfy', function(markers) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                markers[i].setIcon(iconWithColor(usualColor));
                markers[i].setShadow(shadow);
            }
        });

        //Populate data section
        var addMarker = function(lat, lon, name, locationName, unitHref, wellName, runNo, taskDesc, lastDepth, activityMessage, modeMessage) {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lon));

            bounds.extend(myLatlng);

            // COMMENTED OUT CUSTOM MARKER DESCRIPTION TO SAVE SPACE

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                icon: iconWithColor(usualColor),
                shadow: shadow,
                maxWidth: 200
            });
            marker.desc = content;

            oms.addMarker(marker);
            markerArray.push(marker);
        };
        var populateUnits = function() {
            @foreach (var location in Model.Location)
            {
                if (location.Value != null && location.Key != null)
                {
                    @:addMarker('@location.Value.Latitude', '@location.Value.Longitude', '@location.Key.UnitName', '@location.Value.Name', '#', '@location.Key.ViewUnitContract.CurrentRun.Operation.WellContract.Name', '@location.Key.ViewUnitContract.CurrentRun.Id', '@location.Key.ViewUnitContract.CurrentRun.RunTask', '@location.Key.Depth', '@location.Key.ActivityMessage', '@location.Key.ModeMessage');
                }
            }
        };

        //Populate the units
        populateUnits();
        //Add cluster
        markerCluster.addMarkers(markerArray, true);
        //Fit map
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Here's how I loop through the array.

```
function changeMarkers(myArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        myArray[i].setIcon(iconWithColor('a51720'));
    };
}
```

Now, at this point I've just called the `changeMarkers` function upon execution of the script, which works. I've  moved the markerArray out of the `initialize` function, but that's not working either.

Let me clarify what I'd like to do. Say that the page loads, my connection to SignalR spins up and there's no live data available. There might be 10 seconds or 10 hours before I would like to update the color of a marker.

For example, say that two hours have passed, this is what I'd like to do;

```
function someFunc() {
    // Get a reference to the map object
    // Loop through its array of markers
    // if match between marker-id and SignalR data-id
    // update color of marker
}
```

If I just loop through the `markerArray` at any given time *after* the script has executed the first time it will just return an empty set every time. 
I'm kind of lost here :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the marker color by calling `setIcon()`. In your case, when you get an update from SignalR, do something like this...

```
var markerToChange = findMarker(markerArray, dataFromSignalR); // implement findMarker()
markerToChange.setIcon(iconWithColor(dataFromSignalR.color));
```

More details in documentation... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Comment: I guess I can do this at runtime, but the SignalR-values will be updated continuosly. Is it possible to hold a reference to the map somehow to interact with at a later point in time?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your code or your intent, your markerArray is a reference to all the markers on your map (you need to make sure it's in the right scope though so the SignalR callback can access it). But you should be able to use that array to find your marker and update its color. No need to redraw the map or anything.

Comment: Where is your SignalR code (specifically, the callback that is called by SignalR)? Is it on the same page as the rest of these scripts?